# How to access Heroku Web app from POSTMAN?

Tags: api, authentication, heroku, postman

Currently I am running **Web app locally** and I can access local API request using postman.

I would like to know how can I test my API request from postman to the same Web App running on Heroku cloud.

Especially how to send **basic authentication request from postman to Heroku App**?

Comment: Authentication and login are 100% task of your app, heroku doesn't do anything there. 

So it's enough just to use the correct domain.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I'd like to know how to pass authentication login data to server when we send request from POSTMAN.

Comment: The same way you are doing it locally

Comment: Thanks. Now I can access the server inserting username and password in BasicAuth of POSTMAN Authorization tab. Thank you so very much :-)